# How to create a list of iterations where some of the variables are independent and some are dependent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I am trying to make a list of permutations where order matters between the first two variables and the last two variables, but not between those two groups. I have been able to get something like this:

```
>>>[p for p in itertools.product([1, 2],[1, 2],[5, 6], [5, 6])]

   [(1, 1, 5, 5), (1, 1, 5, 6), (1, 1, 6, 5), (1, 1, 6, 6), (1, 2, 5, 5),
    (1, 2, 5, 6), (1, 2, 6, 5), (1, 2, 6, 6), (2, 1, 5, 5), (2, 1, 5, 6), 
    (2, 1, 6, 5), (2, 1, 6, 6), (2, 2, 5, 5), (2, 2, 5, 6), (2, 2, 6, 5), 
    (2, 2, 6, 6)]
```

I would like to get something that doesn't have the switched order repeats, but keeps the duplicate variables, like this:

```
   [(1, 1, 5, 5), (1, 1, 5, 6), (1, 1, 6, 6), (1, 2, 5, 5),(1, 2, 5, 6), 
    (1, 2, 6, 6), (2, 2, 5, 5), (2, 2, 5, 6), (2, 2, 6, 6)]
```

It seems like there should be a straightforward way to do this, I just haven't been able to come up with it yet (I mostly code in R, and have just started looking at Python 3).

Answer (score 1):

Better than using `set` to uniquify the results of `product`, you can combine `product` and `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` to produce the result you care about directly:

```
from itertools import product, combinations_with_replacement as comb_repl

[p1 + p2 for p1, p2 in product(comb_repl([1, 2], 2), comb_repl([5, 6], 2))]
```

This produces the exact output desired, with no duplicates (so no separate deduplication step is required).

Note that for all but the first iterable passed to `product`, `product` will cache the iterable as it goes, so in this case, the complete output of `comb_repl([5, 6], 2)` will end up being stored in memory, as well as all the four-`tuple`s you actually want. That's fine in this case, but if your set of combinations was significantly larger, you might prefer to recompute the combinations as you go, so you only pay memory for the final results, not the complete set of `combinations_with_replacement` outputs for the second iterator. Since `product` caches, you'd have to avoid it, using a multi-`for` list comprehension that repeatedly creates the second `combinations_with_replacement` iterator:

```
# Also switched argument to second comb_repl to a tuple, so argument is not repeatedly rebuilt;
# slightly less readable due to profusion of parens, but equivalent behavior
[p1 + p2 for p1 in comb_repl([1, 2], 2) for p2 in comb_repl((5, 6), 2)]
```

In testing, the nested loop listcomp is slightly slower than using `product` when memory isn't a concern (`product` pushes more work to the C layer, and only creates two instances of `combinations_with_replacement`, not one plus one per output of the first iterator; on the second and subsequent pass, it's iterating the cached `tuple` of outputs, which is as fast as Python gets), so if you know your arguments won't get big enough for the `product` cache to matter, using `product` gets the best performance.

In all cases, unless you really *need* a realized `list`, it's probably better to go with a generator expression (genexpr), as a genexpr only produces results when asked, and doesn't have to store them all in memory; you can loop over it once, after which it exhausted, but in many cases, you only need to loop once and you're done. With a genexpr, usage would look like:

```
# Outer square brackets changed to parentheses
products = (p1 + p2 for p1 in comb_repl([1, 2], 2) for p2 in comb_repl((5, 6), 2))
for p in products:
    ... do stuff with one output ...
```

no more complicated, and for larger combinatorials, won't run out of memory.

Comment: Note: If you wanted to push *all* the work to C, `itertools.starmap(operator.concat, product(comb_repl([1, 2], 2), comb_repl([5, 6], 2)))` will do it, but in testing, this only gets a performance benefit when you want an iterator, not a `list`; `list`ifying the `starmap` is (slightly) slower than the equivalent listcomp, but the `starmap` takes about 20% less time than the equivalent genexpr (both using `product`, not a nested genexpr) when consumed item by item, without storing results (genexprs have slightly higher overhead than listcomps).

Comment: This works perfect, thank you! Memory isn't so much a problem in this case, as it just is meant to generate this list at the beginning of a function based on variables that are used throughout the script.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates, you can use the `set` builtin.

```
>>> set([(1, 1, 5, 6), (1, 2, 6, 5), (1, 1, 5, 6)])
{(1, 1, 5, 6), (1, 2, 6, 5)}
```

Then you can use the `sorted` builtin.

```
>>> sorted([1,2,3,1,0])
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

`sorted` also provides an optional `key` keyword argument, so you could use something like

```
sorted(set(cross_products), key=lambda item: (item[:2], item[-2:]))
```

Which will sort the fields based on the first two and then last two items in the tuple.

Comment: A `key` of `lambda item: (item[:2], item[-2:])` produces the same ordering (via a slightly slower comparison) as `lambda item: item` when each item has four elements, which is the same as not providing a `key` at all. Why bother with it?

Comment: @ShadowRanger __where order matters between the first two variables and the last two variables, but not between those two groups__. My sample `key` was as an example since the OP said they only cared about the first two and last two. If it is not necessary (like in this example where there are only 4 fields), it can obviously be removed.

Comment: True. I suppose the OP was very specific about the ordering constraints, and might have a more complicated problem in mind, so mentioning `key`s might be helpful. Side-note: I love the `operator` module for making sort keys that don't incur Python byte code/function call overhead; this particular `lambda` could be replaced with `operator.itemgetter(slice(2), slice(-2, None))` or slightly more concisely and flattening the key to a single four-`tuple`, `operator.itemgetter(0, 1, -2, -1)`. It's wholly personal preference; I avoid `lambda`s when a self-documenting built-in can do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

```
set([tuple(sorted(p)) for p in itertools.product([1, 2],[1, 2],[5, 6], [5, 6])])
{(1, 1, 5, 5),
 (1, 1, 5, 6),
 (1, 1, 6, 6),
 (1, 2, 5, 5),
 (1, 2, 5, 6),
 (1, 2, 6, 6),
 (2, 2, 5, 5),
 (2, 2, 5, 6),
 (2, 2, 6, 6)}
```

You can just add the function `list()` around everything to get back a list

Comment: Two notes: 1. On 2.7+, a listcomp wrapped in a `set` constructor should be a setcomp: `{tuple(sorted(p)) for p in itertools.product([1, 2],[1, 2],[5, 6], [5, 6])}` that runs faster, with fewer temporaries. 2. The display ordering you're providing is misleading; `set`s do not have predictable ordering (`ipython` will sort them for display to be "helpful", but `list`ifying them gets the true, unpredictable ordering). You'd need to use `sorted`, not `list`, to get a `list` with predictable ordering (in this case, sorting achieves the OP's desired ordering, but that won't always be the case).